# convert C executable file to SIS format

Tags: c, symbian, sis

My  task is to port flite tts to symbian os.  we had tried to compile flite tts and convert it to sis format(the  installation file for symbian os).  There is  a IDE called Qtcreator  which will create  executables  for  mobile devices , for eg Symbian,Meego etc.we used that IDE to compilethe flite tts since flite code was  in c. we were able to compile the code properly and it created flite executables.but we need to convert    it to sis file.that we couldn't do that.  Though it compiles the flite c code properly,to convert executables   for target devices it expects the code to be written in  some other   format(not pure c).at the same time we can't rewrite the full flite   code in that format.it takes time to learn and rewrite.we are really struck here.we don't know how to proceed further.Do you have any idea about this

Comment: Have you tried using the symbian SDK?

Comment: @user1324788 'Though it compiles the flite c code properly,to convert executables for target devices it expects the code to be written in some other format(not pure c).' What do you mean by that? You can compile and deploy simple c programs to symbian and meego devices with Qt Creator. See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-deployment.html

Comment: Did you check the OpenC library and PIPS SDK which allows porting of C code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Hello World application in Qt Creator (or Symbian SDK) and call your C functions from the entry point of the application.